# get existing and non existing combinations between two tables through a relationship table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with this.

I have 3 tables (FROMs, TOs and DISTANCEs):

```
FROMs(Id, Name)
1 - London
2 - Beijing
3 - Athens

TOs(Id, Name)
1 - New York
2 - Madrid
3 - Paris

DISTANCEs(Id,FROMid,TOid,km,obs)
1 - 2 - 3 - 400 - distance between Beij. and Paris
```

I need a query returning this:

```
1    - 2 - 3 - 400 - distance between Beij. and Paris
NULL - 1 - 1 - NULL - NULL
```

and so on for all non-exist combinations.

Thanks.

Comment: What are the column headings for your results? The example you gave shows distance between 1 and 1. According to your data, it is the distance between London and New York.

Comment: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5a0ab) with values

Comment: @MuhammadGhazi - the example shows table `DISTANCE`, id 1, for Beijing (id 2 in the `FROM` table) to paris (id 3 in the `TO`) table.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - I figured that out. I wasn't talking about the table DISTANCEs.

Comment: @MuhammadGhazi - My point was that I'm pretty sure the column headings in the results are the same as the `DISTANCE` table.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - Then why distance between London (Id 1) and New York (Id 1) can be NULL? There appears to be something missing.

Comment: If you think about it, non-existing combination can only exist if one tries to find distance between London and London.

Comment: @MuhammadGhazi - Because it's not in the DISTANCE table

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - How can your query return something which is not in any table?

Comment: @MuhammadGhazi you are right 1 and 1 must be the distance between London and New York but that combination does not exist in DISTANCEs table, so I want the query return existing and NON-EXISTING combinations, those one filled will NULL values in the combination fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do:

Here is a link to [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08c10/18)

```
select a.id, b.fromId, b.toId, a.km, a.obs from distances a
right join(
select a.id as fromId, 
       a.name as fromName,
       b.id as toId,
       b.name as toName
from froms a
join tos b
on 1=1) b
on a.fromId = b.fromId
   and a.toId = b.toId
```

Comment: nor SMARTPHONE neither SMARTTV, this is what must be called a SMART SOLUTION!!!!!!!!  How could you reach it? THANKS A LOT!!!

Comment: Just a little trick with a sub query join to get all variations; the rest is trivial. Enjoy.